# SVG with drop-shadow blurry on mobile browser

Tags: css, svg, blurry, drop-shadow

i am struggling to make work SVG icons with drop-shadow on as much as possible platforms.

I am using following simple CSS for that:

```
.test{
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  background-image: url("../images/test.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.8;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0px #E0E0E0);
}
```

On Desktop browsers like Chrome, Firefox & IE its working good.
But on mobile Browser the problems begin: In Chrome the icon gets blurry & in Firefox the drop-shadow is just ignored. When removing the drop-shadow, the icon will be clear again in Chrome, so i think it has something in common with the drop-shadow.

Anyone had the same problem and found maybe a solution for this?

Comment: Please file a bug at http://crbug.com including a testcase and more details on which versions it affects.

Comment: I just stumbled across the same problem, nobody else seems to be aware of it, though...

Comment: Yes I'm surprised the lack of info about this bug, especially as it was flagged years ago..!?

Answer (score 6):

Just found the answer for it.
This problem occurs due to the way SVG filters are generated: Before a filter is applied, a bitmap image of the respective element is created which is then manipulated and layered on top. You can find a great explanation [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/?redirect_from_locale=de).

To show svg images sharp on HDPI screens, you can try using the `filterRes`-property on the `effect`, which provides a pixel resolution for calculated svg effects, more on that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/filterRes).
Use it like so:

```
<filter id="dropshadow" height="170%" filterRes="200">
  <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="20"/>
  <feOffset dx="0" dy="2" result="offsetblur"/>
  <feMerge> 
    <feMergeNode/>
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic"/>
  </feMerge>
</filter>
<path id="icon" fill="#fff" style="filter:url(#dropshadow)" d="..."></path>
</svg>
```

Say you add `background-size: contain` to your css - the drawn container will presumably be `14px x 14px`. To render the shadow with sufficient resolution for retina displays (eg. factor **2**), you should take a healthy value of `30` for `filterRes`. This is not ideal, but it seems like it is the only working alternative at the moment. Kind of defeats the reason for using svg at all.

Comment: This has no effect for me, safari 12.1.1. filterRes is deprecated now https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/filterRes