# SVG's <feDropShadow /> look different (blurred) in Safari and the rest browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, safari

It's a magic, but I face a weird behavior in `svg`'s shadow appearing on `Safari`. Seems like it does not want to deal with `feDropShadow` normally, like it can the rest part of browsers (`Chrome` for example). It makes a figure blurred and unclear to look.

So, if you run my snippet below in both `Safari` and `Chrome`, you'll totally see the difference between `svg` `stars` once zoomed.

I've also saw these posts, but they're unrelevant:

- [SVG with drop-shadow blurry on mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351902/svg-with-drop-shadow-blurry-on-mobile-browser)
- [SVG filters fuzzy in Safari under some circumstances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47942581/svg-filters-fuzzy-in-safari-under-some-circumstances)

A little code to reproduce:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My first SVG</h1>

<svg width="100" height="100">
   <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
   Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg> 

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="default___3oPC0 " stroke="transparent" stroke-width="0" width="34" height="34" viewBox="-2.3 -2.1 9 9" 

fill="url(#sidebar_svg_gradient_regular_desktop_gold)"
filter="url(#svg_sidebar_green_regular_desktop_gold_filter)"


>
<filter id="svg_sidebar_green_regular_desktop_gold_filter">
 <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="0" flood-color="#f4b701" stdDeviation="1.2"></feDropShadow>
</filter>

<linearGradient id="sidebar_svg_gradient_regular_desktop_gold" gradientTransform="rotate(90)" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"><stop offset="0" stop-color="#f4b701"></stop><stop offset="1" stop-color="#b08505"></stop></linearGradient>


<path d="M2.5,0l.59,1.82H5L3.45,2.94l.6,1.82L2.5,3.63,1,4.76l.6-1.82L0,1.82H1.91Z"></path>

</svg>
 
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**

Seems like a problem is hiding inside webKit engine core itself, based on the still opened report from far 2013: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=119300

I've found some solution for my case. It doesn't perfect, but could totally work for Safari: https://github.com/artdecocode/daily-log/blob/master/shadow.md

Resource: [SVG: Drop-Shadow filter pixelates SVG on mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664407/svg-drop-shadow-filter-pixelates-svg-on-mobile-safari)

Comment: Maybe your issue is [one of these](https://bugs.webkit.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&content=feDropShadow&no_redirect=1&order=Importance&query_format=specific) if not, you should probably raise a new issue on that bugtracker.

Comment: @RobertLongson thank you. You're right! Meanwhile, seems like the bugtracker above is dead for a while. So, i don't think it's still a hope to be hear there...

Comment: Still haven't found a proper solution for this, other than using pngs, or putting the svg inline, which still looks a little blurry sometimes...